# How do I keep images from flashing when rendering Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js as a framework, and in my view I have a few small images (a trash can to delete, an icon, etc.). And when the view re-renders these images flash.

I have solved this with larger images by creating a new view for everything I don't want to flash - and not triggering them to render. But I was wondering if there is another way to do this without breaking up my view into a bunch of pieces?

This is the general format I am rendering my views in:

```
window.SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {                
        this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);
        this.template = _.template($('#view-template').html());
    },
    render: function(){
        var renderedContent = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        $(this.el).html(renderedContent);
        return this;
    },
    events: { 'click .delete' : delete },
    delete: function(ev){
        //do delete stuff here
    },

});
```

And then I attach them to a div by:

```
var newView = new PopupItemImgView({model: someModel});
        $('#styleimage').append(newView.render().el);
```

My template might look like

```
<script type="text/template" id="view-template">
<%
    print('Content content - <img src="images/delete.gif" class="delete">');
%>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code

Comment: can you show a bit of code on how you re-render?  My assumption is that you are removing your html, including the images, from the dom and then re-adding them.

Comment: Mike, yes, that's how I learned to do it from tutorials. I attached some code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding the `change` event to your `render` method, you might bind `change` to an `onChange` function.  Then, within the `onChange` handler, you could figure out exactly what needs to be updated, and leave everything else as-is.

I used this approach when I build a view for a collection: I didn't want the whole list to re-render when a single element changed.  Instead, I rendered once when the element was first inserted, and then handled specific change events as necessary.